# How to propagate an error code outside a terminal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, process, exit

From inside a bash script I try to retrieve the error code of a program launched in a new terminal window. It can be reduced to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
urxvt -e bash -c "exit 4"
echo $?
```

output: 0

I would like to access the "4" in my script that is calling urxvt.
How can I do that please? :)

Comment: You can change the second line to this : urxvt -e bash -c ' bash -c " exit 4 " ; echo $? > error.code ' . Then read the return code from the file "error.code" . That worked for me.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I think that is the reasonable way to do it. I encourage you to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK graphical terminals such as `uxvrt` doesn't have any utility to give you the return code of the program you've run on them.

The best and most straightforward way that came into my mind is to run a sub-shell inside your `bash` ( looks a little cluttered , but trust me ) and run whatever program you want inside the inner `bash` and use the outer one to handle the return code as follows :

```
urxvt -e bash -c ' (exit 4) ; echo $? > error.code '
```

Now you can read the return code from the file `error.code`.

Note that the existence of a temporary file is necessary since if you just `echo` the return code , it gets printed in the `urxvt` window which itself will get closed after a few thousands of the second.So you wouldn't get anything useful.

Comment: you might also streamline it all within a command-substitution doing redirection inside, as in: `status=$(exec urxvt -e sh -c '(exit 4); echo $? >&3' 3>&1)`

Comment: @LL3 Nice ! That's another way of achieving this . But I wonder why is " fd 3 " still open after the shell finished ? Is it somehow related to "exec" ? And how is it possible to write into a file descriptor which is not open ?

Comment: fd 3 is made a copy of fd 1 in the command-substitution, which keeps it open all along; then fd 3 is passed naturally through to the inner shell and used by `echo`; the `exec` is admittedly just a perfectionism of mine so as not to have useless processes around, and assumes that `urxvt` will be the only command executed by the command-substitution; you may get rid of `exec` and everything will function as desired by OP anyway; however this is not another way to achieve this, it's rather your same way just enhanced to get rid of the temporary file

Comment: Thank you @LL3 I used your elegant solution!

Comment: @LL3 You can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi No problem you may embed my note in your answer if you like, in which case I will just delete my comments. After all the basic idea is really just the same as yours. Besides, the use of a temporary file is yet again needed if any intermediate command (just `urxvt` in this case) does not propagate fds down to its children (does not apply to `urxvt` or `xterm` because they do propagate fds), but then there might be corner cases to handle if you use the same temporary file for 2+ “exit statuses” simultaneously..

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion on Parsa Mousavi's answer. Although it does the job, you will lose the track with quotes if what you want to execute is more complex than `exit 4`, as is probably the case.

A more flexible alternative is

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunc(){
    (
    #Other statements...
    exit 4
    )
    echo $? > errorcode
}

export -f myfunc

uxrvt -e bash -c 'myfunc'
echo "Error code:"
cat errorcode
```

The export is necessary so that the `bash` executed in the new terminal gets the function too.

The POSIX shell does not allow for function export. For a portable alternative, create two scripts, for simplicity in the same directory:

`main`:

```
#!/bin/sh
urxvt -e sh -c './secondary'
echo "Error code of secondary:"
cat errorcode
```

`secondary`:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfunc(){
    #Here your statements...
    exit 4
}

(myfunc)
echo $? > errorcode
```

Make both executable (`chmod +x main secondary`) and run `./main`. You should get

```
Error code of secondary:
4
```

Notice that `myfunc` runs in a subshell, otherwise the program would be terminated and the `echo $?` line would never be executed.